# Generalisation and Categorisation in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2005

I have to implement a database in which there is categorization and generalisation. A customer entity exists which can be categorized into Person, Government or Company. Further there exists an overlap generalisation in which the customer can be an E-Commerce or Walk-in or both and there is a distinct generalisation in which the customer can either be an Employee or a regular Customer.

I have implemented the tables as follows:

**Customer**

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    First_order_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id)
);
```

**Person**

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id)
);
```

**Company**

```
CREATE TABLE Company
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id)
);
```

**Goverment**

```
CREATE TABLE Government
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id)
);
```

**Employee**

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    Employee _cutomer_name CHAR(15),
    Employee_discount_rate FLOAT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_id)
);
```

**Regular**

```
CREATE TABLE Regular
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    Regular_cutomer_name CHAR(15),
    Regular_cutomer_address CHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_id)
);
```

**WalkIn**

```
CREATE TABLE WalkIn
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    Walkin_cutomer_name CHAR(15),
    Walkin_cutomer_address CHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_id)
);
```

**ECommerce**

```
CREATE TABLE ECommerce
(
    Customer_id CHAR(4),
    Ecommerce_cutomer_name CHAR(15),
    Ecommerce_cutomer_email CHAR(80),
    PRIMARY KEY(Customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(Customer_id)
);
```

How do I ensure that the generalisation and categorisation constraints are met in my database?

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand your question perfectly. If I have to design this kind of database at my work.I will do that with General `Customer` class with 2 columns distinguish customer type.

### General Customer Table

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  customer_id CHAR(4),
  type1 ENUM("Person", "Company", "Government"),
  type2 ENUM("Employee", "Regular", "WalkIn", "ECommerce"),
  first_order_date DATE,
  name CHAR(15),
  address CHAR(80),

  email CHAR(80),
  discount_rate FLOAT
);
```

all customer has type1, type2, frst_order_date, name, address. but only ECommerce user has email, only employee has discount_rate. this value will be NULL for other customer type. if you this is not good, then `option` table can help you.

### Genernal Customer table + Option Table

```
CREATE TABLE customer
(
  customer_id CHAR(4),
  type1 ENUM("Person", "Company", "Government"),
  type2 ENUM("Employee", "Regular", "WalkIn", "ECommerce"),
  first_order_date DATE,
  name CHAR(15),
  address CHAR(80)
);

CREATE TABLE option_tbl
(
  customer_id CHAR(4),
  option_name CHAR(10),
  option_value VARCHAR(80),
  FOREING KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(customer_id)
);
```

also this design has trade off.

- email and discount has different data type.
- hard to check 1 Employee must have 1 discount_rate. customer and option_tbl is one to many relation.

### FYI

- in practice, `ENUM` is not good. refer http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/
- first_order_date is de-normalized. that means it is redundant and inconsistency can be happened. to find first order date join customer and order table. if performance is poor then de-normalize it.
- `FLOAT` type is not good, `NUMERIC` is better. `NUMERIC` is fixed point
- If I were you I'll take 1st design.